# ElasticSearch ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'elasticsearch.compat'

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I get this import error when trying to run

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, A
```

Full traceback

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'elasticsearch.compat' (C:\Users\SANA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\elasticsearch\compat.py)
```

elasticsearch version: 7.13.3
elasticsearch-dsl version: 7.4.0

I have tried:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
```

And can't seem to google my way to an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have installed elasticsearch_dsl. Install elasticsearch-dsl.

Try doing :

```
pip uninstall elasticsearch_dsl
pip install elasticsearch-dsl
```

this should work.

Comment: Why can we install both `elasticsearch_dsl` and `elasticsearch-dsl` yet they behave differently? this is very confusing?